# Do I need multithreading for my game?

Tags: android, multithreading, opengl-es

I'm trying to make a simple breakout game with opengl es, on Android, and I can't decide wether I have to use a seperate thread for certain game logic stuff, like updating the game and collission detection. I've prototyped a simple one: Drawing and Updating parallel of eachother in their own thread. It brought more problems than I thought, and so I thought:

> Do I need more than one thread?

Since a breakout game for example, has like 6X5 grid of blocks, and for each block it needs to test
Does the ball touch this brick? And about 30 times a second. If I put this code in my main Drawing loop: OnDrawFrame(GL10) I'm afraid it will cost alot of rendering time.
So can I just return to single threaded game, or not? (since Android devices are not that powerful compared to ..pc's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm trying to make a simple breakout game

No, you do not need to thread anything.

Threading is not for "simple" tasks. Threading is for tasks where you can reasonably expect significant problems with performance, such that you would actually gain something by going multithreaded.

What you will gain by threading a Breakout clone is a coding headache. Nothing more. It simply isn't significant enough to require it, and if you don't *need* threading, you should almost never use it.

Comment: I disagree. Multi-threading doesn't have to be difficult and in many ways can make the logic of a game more understandable and easier to work on.  For example it makes a lot of sense to put the drawing of the game in a single thread and the mechanics of the game in another thread. Those are two things that should be separated in code anyway. So it shouldn't be too difficult to give them their own threads.

Comment: @slayton: And then you have to communicate across the thread boundary. Which is going to require, at the very least, some kind of multithreaded queue, where one thread can read from it and one thread can write to it. That is _not_ something that anyone starting on a Breakout game can manage to do correctly. Threading is hard even for experts; for a novice, it is a giant trap that will leave them debugging for weeks if not months, with no idea why one out of every thousand games causes a random crash.

Comment: in a simple case you really don't need to use a multithreaded queue just make your methods `synchronized` but you are right in that multi threading requires you to think about what you are doing more so than in a single threaded application. However, knowing how to make multi-threaded applications is valuable skill and really isn't that difficult to get the hang of.  My advise is always to tell young programmers that they don't have to use it but inform them why they should.

Comment: I absolutely agree, that multithreading can easily lead to random/synchronization bugs and crashes and the more experience you have the better. **Very Big Gotcha** here is that in the question `OnDrawFrame(GL10)` is mentioned, when using OpenGL|ES through GLSurfaceView then that code is already running on a separate thread (the GLThread, that class creates).

Comment: FWIW, http://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/ is a GLES 2 Breakout game that uses GLSurfaceView.  There are two "interesting" threads, the main app UI thread, and the Renderer thread.  The game runs almost entirely in Renderer, which avoids most multithreading issues, but it still has to be careful around startup / shutdown and when receiving touch events from the app UI thread.

Comment: I use my gpu for even a simple array value searching, so how do you agree with single thread approach for a GAME?! how do you run [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616115/Java-Thread-Example#lc) example with single-thread? there is no any formula for identifying use or not use threads!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should definitely not be using a single thread for your rendering and calculations.
As an aside you might find the IO talk on realtime android games [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4Bk5rmIpic) useful.

Comment: It's a breakout clone. Do you really think that's going to matter?

Comment: From the video in my comment if you jump to about 20:00 there's a discussion of this and why it's just generally not good to have all your calculations be blocked by hardware rendering. Can you get away with calculating in your draw loop for something this simple? Maybe. But threading isn't all that difficult and it's probably worth biting the bullet

Comment: I coded a Breakout clone in interpreted Pascal on a 486, using horribly inefficient drawing routines. I think Android devices can handle it. Also, "hardware rendering" doesn't block the CPU; the only time the CPU is blocked by the GPU is if you swap buffers. And even then, that's assuming that the graphics driver itself isn't threaded.

Answer (score 2):

> Since a breakout game for example, has like 6X5 grid of blocks, and for each block it needs to test

So you have to perform 30 circle-recangle tests per update. I think current computers are fast enough to do this a few hundred of thousand times a second.

Multithreading makes some things easier, and keeping rendering and game logic in separate threads is a common practice. But in your case the overhead that comes with it is simply not worth the effort. Also a gain in performance is only achieveable on multicore CPUs.

Comment: You will not only see a gain in performance on multicore CPUs because drawing is blocked by hardware rendering time which leaves the CPU mostly idle.

Comment: @jqpubliq: This strongly depends on how you organize your drawing function. For example if you take a carefull timing of start of rendering to a closing glFinish, and knowing the screen refresh, one can use the remaining time (minus a guard interval) to do work, before issueing a SwapBuffers. However the total available CPU time will not increase by using multithreading. But like I said, using multithreading make things easier, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading make sense if your application is supposed to run on multicore systems.

When # of threads exceeds number of cores it is called Oversubscription, which is usually bad effect in threaded applications because it gives additional overhead.

Sometimes oversubscription is intended when you expect some threads to be waiting for considerable amount of time (e.g. read/write operation on filesystem).

Comment: There are many more reasons to use multithreading other than parallel processing.  They've existed  and have been used since the days of single-core processors, afterall.

Comment: There are lots of reasons to using multiple threads and most of them have nothing to do with the number of CPU cores. Multi-threading an application can allow you to take advantage of multiple cores.

Comment: how do you say it? so you mean a single core celeron cpu would just run 1 thread overall? do you know about context switching?